# z3 Prover for solving the Abstract syntax tree

Tags: z3

I want to convert AST(Abstract syntax tree) to the input constraints of Z3, How can I do that ? [This process is for test pattern generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7lOe.jpg)

Comment: Is your question about Z3's ASTs or about ASTs of your own application? For the first you can use Z3's translations to SMT2 strings (via the Z3_*_to_string functions).

Comment: I mean the AST of my own application which i got it by using pyverilog.

Comment: In that case the SMT tutorial is probably the best starting point, see here: http://smtlib.github.io/jSMTLIB/SMTLIBTutorial.pdf