# Convert my pyverilog AST to input for Z3 solver

Tags: python, verilog, smt, z3py

I have converted my verilog file to AST(abstrct syntax tree) but along with external constraints like the output for the circuit and the AST is to be given to Z3/SMT solver which should give us the inputs for the circuit, but I have no idea how can I give AST as the inputs for Z3/SMT solver.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems very similar to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44582189/z3-prover-for-solving-the-abstract-syntax-tree

Did Christoph's advice regarding following the SMTLib tutorial not yield any insight?

Comment: I am still confused about linking my file to the Z3 solver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a task typically amounts to walking over your AST and symbolically executing it, and generating a trace for the SMT solver. *This is easier said then done, unfortunately:* there are many facets of doing this translation and even when done fully, it is far from easy for a solver to verify the corresponding properties. For full Verilog, you'd have to essentially implement a Verilog simulator that can deal with symbolic values. While this can be a very large task, perhaps you can get away with a much smaller set of features, if your inputs are "simple" enough. Without knowing anything about how your Verilog is structured, it's really hard to say anything.

This [paper](http://fm.csl.sri.com/SSFT14/smt-application-chapter.pdf), penned by the two main authors of Z3 (Nikolaj and Leonardo) provides a good survey of the approach. It's an excellent read with many useful references. Starting with that can at least give you an idea of what's involved.

I should add that verification of Verilog designs is a topic that has industrial applications, and there are vendor supported tools (not cheap!) to do verification at the Verilog level. The [Jasper Gold](https://www.cadence.com/content/cadence-www/global/en_US/home/tools/system-design-and-verification/formal-and-static-verification/jasper-gold-verification-platform.html?cmp=dmzweb1) tool from Cadence is one such example. [Synopsys](https://www.synopsys.com/verification/static-and-formal-verification.html) also has a similar tool.

It seems you are interested in test-case generation. That would correspond to writing a typical "cover" property, and reading off of the values to primary inputs that lead to the cover scenario in such a setting. Such properties are typically written in the [SVA](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/sysverilog/tutorial/assertions/) format, which is understood by such tools.